# Reference request for elementary geometry.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a graduate student of Mathematics.Although I am doing good in my Masters' courses,I have to admit that I am a bit weak in basic Mathematics specially in elementary geometry.So,in this summer vacation I am planning to brush up those topics and fix my weakness.But,unfortunately,I have not found any reference that covers all the topics in geometry e.g. lines,angles,triangles,circles,tangents,quadrilaterals,rectangles,parallelograms.I am looking for a book that I can follow as textbook.Can someone suggest me a reference?

**Addendum**

I have tried Euclid's elements but it is not very helpful.So,please suggest a book that is good for beginners.

Comment: "Introduction to Geometry" by Richard Rusczyk is a well-written book that starts from the very basics of Euclidean geometry and gradually leads to more challenging material. https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/book/intro-geometry

Comment: Axiomatic geometry by Lee is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think on several options, one of them is [Elementary Geometry from an advanced standpoint](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3295413-elementary-geometry-from-an-advanced-standpoint) by E.Moise. But if you are looking for exercises like in math olympiads, there is a lot of material like in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community

I would suggest reading [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15857/coxeters-geometry-revisited-vs-introduction-to-geometry) also.